# Javascript Promise handler called before beeing resolved

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

In an effort to remove the use of jQuery from my code, I tried to replace the `$.Deferred();` by `new Promise()`.

I noticed the usage are slightly different, and I'm still learning how it works.

Here is a simplified extract from my code:

```
function do_match (resolve, reject) {
    fetch( /* ... */).then (async function(response) {
        /* do some suff */
        document.getElementById("match").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="player"></div>');
        resolve("done");
    });
}

function do_myMarket () {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.player');
    //here elements is sometimes null...
}

p1 = new Promise(do_match);
p1.then(do_myMarket, null);
```

While I would have expect `do_myMarket` to only be called after the promise is resolved, if the fetch is not fast enough, `do_myMarket` can be called before the elements are available in the page.

Putting breakpoints if `elements` is null and `resolve()` confirmed me this behavior.

Am I missing something? Why would this happen?

Comment: You're using the [explicit promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Also [you shouldn't ever use `async` executors for promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor).

Comment: just add await or return before fetch...

Comment: @DmitriyMozgovoy Why?

Comment: I "fixed" the issue with a `await`, that's probably why the function is `async` (I may forgot to clean it before writing the question).
But to me this looks more like a hack than a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some readings from @VLAZ and more testing, I found out it's because of the `async` in the unnamed function.

The promise `p1` was resolved by the return value of the `fetch` function, which would not wait for completion because of the `async` keyword, thus making `resolve("done");` useless.
And  I tried, same behavior with or without the call to `resolve`.

This comes from, what I think now, as a wacky example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#An_Ajax_Call):

```
// Function to do an Ajax call
const doAjax = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('Ajax.php'); // Generate the Response object
    if (response.ok) {
        const jVal = await response.json(); // Get JSON value from the response body
        return Promise.resolve(jVal);
        }
    else
        return Promise.reject('*** PHP file not found');
    }
}

// Call the function and output value or error message to console
doAjax().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

The above is **all antipattern** if I understood correctly.

The correct way is the page dedicated to the [.json() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json):

```
function doAjax() {
    fetch(/* ... */)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            //...
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
```